# Django NoReverseMatch Error With Namespacing

Tags: python, django, url

I have this in my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^ding/', include('ding.urls', namespace='ding', app_name='ding')),
```

And this in my ding/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', views.sign_in, name='sign_in'),
                       url(r'^connect/$', views.connect, name='connect'),
                       url(r'^disconnect/$', views.disconnect, name='disconnect'),
                       #url(r'^disconnect/sign_in/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse('sign_in')), name="disconnect_sign_in"),
                       url(r'^search$', views.search, name='search'),
                       url(r'^parsed_query/(?P<query>.+)/(?P<scroll_num>(\-|)\d+)/$', views.get_search_results, name='get_search_results'),
                       url(r'^parsed_query/', views.parsed_query, name='parsed_query'),
                       url(r'^parsed_query_redirect/', views.parsed_query_redirect, name='parsed_query_redirect'),
)
```

Calling any of the following:

```
print reverse('sign_in', current_app='ding')
print reverse('connect', current_app='ding')
print reverse('disconnect', current_app='ding')
...
```

results in a NoReverseMatch error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reverse('ding:sign_in')
```

reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces

Make sure you know the difference between application namespace and instance namespace:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces
I find that rarely both are needed (but of course there are plenty of use cases where they are).